# Is the word ogle in common use and is it pejorative?

Tags: word-meaning

I found that one in a sentence like this:

> The last thing she needed was another man ogling her body.

So is that kind of pejorative saying, implying that man are pigs or just a different word for staring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, yes it is in common use.

Secondly, it does have the nuance of looking in a sexual manner.  Not just a man looking at a woman, it is used for a woman looking at a man.

A stare would be a more fixed look than an ogle, which implies casting the eyes over the body.  A phrase sometimes used is "mental undressing".  Further, a leer is a look with an expression of desire, which may be a precursor to attempted seduction.

Comment: That's pretty much what I wanted to know. Thanks! A leer - new word to remember ;)